# Creating a subquery with mysqli in PHP to fetch array last 10 results in ascending order

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I thought this would be simple but I'm having a tough time figuring out why this won't populate the the data array.

This simple query works fine:

```
$queryPrice = "SELECT price FROM price_chart ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 50";
$resultPrice = mysqli_query($conn, $queryPrice);
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultPrice)) {
$data[] = $row[0];
}
```

But instead I want it to choose the last 10 results in Ascending order. I found on other SO questions to use a subquery but every example I try gives no output and no error ??

Tried the below, DOESN'T WORK:

```
$queryPrice = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT price FROM price_chart ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) ORDER BY id ASC";
$resultPrice = mysqli_query($conn, $queryPrice);
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultPrice)) {
$data[] = $row[0];
}
```

I also tried specifying the table name again and using the IN, also doesn't work:

```
$queryPrice = "SELECT price FROM price_chart IN (SELECT price FROM price_chart ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) ORDER BY id";
$resultPrice = mysqli_query($conn, $queryPrice);
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultPrice)) {
$data[] = $row[0];
}
```

In both examples my array is blank instead of returning the last 10 results and there are no errors, so I must be doing the subquery wrong and it is returning 0 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery doesn't select the `id` column, so you can't order by it in the outer query. Also, MySQL requires that you assign an alias when you use a subquery in a `FROM` or `JOIN` clause.

```
$queryPrice = "SELECT * 
                FROM (SELECT id, price 
                        FROM price_chart 
                        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
                ) x ORDER BY id ASC";
$resultPrice = mysqli_query($conn, $queryPrice) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultPrice)) {
    $data[] = $row['price'];
}
```

You would have been notified of these errors if you called `mysqli_error()` when the query fails.

Answer (score 1):

You must have errors, because your SQL queries are in fact incorrect.

First, how to tell you have errors:

```
$resultPrice = mysqli_query (whatever);
if ( !$resultprice ) echo mysqli_error($conn);
```

Second: subqueries in MySQL need aliases.  So you need this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT id, price
         FROM price_chart
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
       ) AS a
ORDER BY id ASC";
```

See the `) AS a`? That's the table alias.

Comment: Note this will err on the order by, because there is no `id` in the subquery.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked! I had to change my while loop from a num array [0] to assoc array ['prices'] as Barmar answered showed, so I picked him as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your second query is the closest.  However you need a table alias.  (You would have seen this if you were kicking out errors in your sql.  Note you will need to add any field that you wish to order by in your subquery.  In this case it is `id`.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT price, id 
FROM price_chart ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) as prices 
ORDER BY id ASC
```